# Submit button problem when I have more than 1 tab?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, submit

I have a problem submitting a form in laravel 7. I can explain the situation:

My form label is

```
<form action="/boards/{{$data->id}}/send" 
        id="submit_form_all" 
        method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    @csrf
```

And inside the form, I have 3 div (It is a tab pane, I have done it with materializeCSS):

```
<div id="configPrincipalipal" class="col s12 ">
    ... 
</div>    
<div id="controAcceso" class="col s12 controAccesoDiv">
    ...
</div>    
<div id="agendaConf" class="col s12 agendaConfDiv " style="margin-bottom:10%">
    ...
</div>
```

And after that, I have 2 buttons:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light offset-s6 red"  href="#" name="action">
    {{Lang ::get('agendaContactos.backButt')}}
    <i class="material-icons left">arrow_back</i>
</button>    
<button onclick="submit_form()" class="btn waves-effect waves-light offset-s6 blue" name="action" >
    {{Lang ::get('agendaContactos.subButt')}}
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

I tried with input type="submit" / button type="submit" and this example is with a function submit_form() ->

```
function submit_form() {
    console.log("sending");
    $("#submit_form_all").submit();
}
```

I can see the sending text, so the button arrives to the function.
If I put the button just after the 1st div with id configPrincipal, then I arrive to controller, but if I put the button after that (for example 1 line after opening the second div), the form is not submitted and it do not anything, I got no response on the console either.

This is an image of the website:
[image: Website with the tabs]

Comment: Does the input type submit worked for you?

Comment: No, not worked..

Comment: If input type submits outside the `<form>` tag then submit button not work. But in your case, you have used jquery for submitting the form so `submit_form` should work. Can you check `dd($request->all());` in your controller?

Comment: Hi Amit, I tried the dd($request) at the first lane of the controller, but do not arrives here, i think it happens because a bug related with tabs in materializeCSS, I have read in another posts that in Bootstrap happens with tabs too, but I do not have idea.

Comment: Ok but I do not know `materialize CSS` so take care

Comment: I will try to create a empty form, and add a function that put all the inputs inside the new form and submit it, let's try it haha

Comment: it is working right?

Comment: I am doing it at now, it works I think, but let me add all inputs and I will tell you!